# Amazon business API - order items not mapped to Amazon business account

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, soap

We are trying to integrate the Amazon business API into the website.

This is the flow of the project. The fund raiser will add the products from amazon business api into the project and later admin approve/publish the project into the website. Once the fund is collected for the respective project through the website. The admin will buy the products from the amazon.

We have generated the amazon e-procurement punchout URL with that we are able to enter into amazon business website and adding products to the cart. After clicking on the “Submit these items for approval” we are able get the cart response in our project. But the issue is order id is not generated and not able to see those orders in amazon website administrator account “Approve Orders” page.

Below are the request codes that we are sending to amazon business. Please guide/suggest us where we have done the mistake.

Punchout setup request:

```
<?php
    $soapUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/eprocurement/punchout";
    $xml_post_string = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
      <!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.007/cXML.dtd">
      <cXML version="1.2.007" xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="123456.123456@amazon.com" timestamp="2016-09-01T01:50:29-05:00">
      <Header>
        <From>
          <Credential domain="NetworkId">
            <Identity>abcd123</Identity>
          </Credential>
        </From>
        <To>
           <Credential domain="NetworkId">
             <Identity>Amazon</Identity>
           </Credential>
        </To>
        <Sender>
           <Credential domain="NetworkId">
              <Identity> abcd123</Identity>
              <SharedSecret>test secret</SharedSecret>
           </Credential>
           <UserAgent>amazon.com</UserAgent>
        </Sender>
      </Header>
      <Request>
        <PunchOutSetupRequest operation="create">
          <BuyerCookie>1234567</BuyerCookie>
          <Extrinsic name="RequestID">5826623</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="MUDID">CLS21518</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="Location">RTP</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="Country">UNITED STATES</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="Email">user@email.org</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="ClientMUDID">CLS21518</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="UserEmail">user@email.org</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="Division">Corporate</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="StartDate">1/9/2016 2:34:36 PM</Extrinsic>
          <BrowserFormPost>
            <URL>http://www.test.com/ test/response.php</URL>
          </BrowserFormPost>
          <Contact>
            <Name xml:lang="en-US">Jones, Tom</Name>
            <Email>user@email.org</Email>
          </Contact>
          <SupplierSetup>
            <URL>http://workchairs.com/cxml</URL>
          </SupplierSetup>
        </PunchOutSetupRequest>
      </Request>
      </cXML>';

    $headers = array(
      "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
      "Accept: text/xml",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      "Pragma: no-cache",
      "SOAPAction: https://www.amazon.com/eprocurement/punchout",
      "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    );

    $url = $soapUrl;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($parser); exit;
?>
```

***Punchout setup response:***

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [payloadID] => 1234567981324.123.1234@amazon.com
            [timestamp] => 2016-09-01T10:37:29+10:37
        )

    [Response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => 200
                            [text] => success
                        )

                )

            [PunchOutSetupResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [StartPage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [URL] => https://www.amazon.com/eprocurement/initiate-clean-punchout/123-1234567-1234567
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Punchout Order Message:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [payloadID] => 1234567981234.105.9597@amazon.com
            [timestamp] => 2016-09-01T10:37:53.985Z
        )

    [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [From] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Credential] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [domain] => DUNS
                                        )

                                    [Identity] => 123465789
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [domain] => NetworkId
                                        )

                                    [Identity] => Amazon
                                )

                        )

                )

            [To] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Credential] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [domain] => NetworkId
                                )

                            [Identity] => abcd123
                        )

                )

            [Sender] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Credential] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [domain] => DUNS
                                        )

                                    [Identity] => 123456789
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [domain] => NetworkId
                                        )

                                    [Identity] => Amazon
                                )

                        )

                    [UserAgent] => Amazon LLC eProcurement Application
                )

        )

    [Message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [PunchOutOrderMessage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [BuyerCookie] => 1234567
                    [PunchOutOrderMessageHeader] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [operationAllowed] => create
                                )

                            [Total] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Money] => 1.88
                                )

                        )

                    [ItemIn] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                )

                            [ItemID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [SupplierPartID] => D00004ABC1
                                    [SupplierPartAuxiliaryID] => 123-1234567-1234567,1
                                )

                            [ItemDetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [UnitPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [Money] => 1.88
                                        )

                                    [Description] => Mead Composition Book, Wide Ruled, 9.75 x 7.50 Inch Sheet Size, Black Marble, Bookbound, 100 Sheets (09910)
                                    [UnitOfMeasure] => EA
                                    [Classification] => 14111514
                                    [ManufacturerPartID] => UPC-800187711702
                                    [ManufacturerName] => MeadWestvaco Consumer & Office Products
                                    [Extrinsic] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Amazon
                                            [1] => Amazon
                                            [2] => gl_office_product
                                            [3] => OFFICE_PRODUCTS
                                            [4] => New
                                            [5] => true
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

We receive the response from Amazon business successfully. But the order details is not mapped with the actual amazon business account.

In order to purchase the products once fund is available from the admin side. The order details need to available in the Amazon business account.

Is there anything we are missing the request script? Or is there any settings that needs to be made in Amazon business account?

Comment: Try the request using https method.

Comment: @fairoz, We have tried the request method though HTTPS. Now, the amazon admin account receives email. But the order items details not available in "Approve Orders". Please advise?

Comment: Hi. With your Amazon Business punchout project, did you ever work on punching out to specific departments, like "Books" etc???